Solve the differential equation $x dy - y dx = x\sqrt{x^{2} - y^{2}}dx$ using Inspection Method.
Solve the differential equation $x dy - y dx = x\sqrt{x^{2} - y^{2}}dx$ using Inspection Method.
My Attempt :
Rearranging the given equation in the form :
$$(x\sqrt{x^{2} - y^{2}} + y) dx  - x dy = 0$$
Now comparing it with $Mdx + Ndx = 0$ and calculating the partial derivatives we get $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$. So the equation is non-exact differential equation.
$$x dy - y dx = x\sqrt{x^{2} - y^{2}} dx$$
Dividing both sides by $y^{2}$ we get,
$$-d(\frac {x}{y}) = \frac {x}{y} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}}{y} \, dx$$
How do we move further from here?

You're almost there---just rewrite second factor of the right-hand side as $(\operatorname{sign} y) \sqrt{\left(\frac xy\right)^2 - 1}$.
Alternatively, write $y(x) = x u(x)$, so that the equation becomes
$$u'(x) = (\operatorname{sign} x) \sqrt{1 - u(x)^2} ,$$
which is separable.

What is (sign $y$)? And why are we using that here?

$\operatorname{sign}$ is the function that sends positive numbers to $1$, $0$ to $0$, and negative numbers to $-1$. It's necessary here because (e.g., in its first appearance in the answer) $\sqrt{y^2} = |y| = y \operatorname{sign} y$.
